# C++ add 65279 BOM character at start of reading file, using ifstream?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When i want to read text from file and write that text to  another file it write 65279 character in start of that file. Im using this code for reading from file:

```
int libery(){
    string location;
    textfromcode = "";
    ifstream libs;
    location=loc.c_str();
    location.append("/");
    location.append(path.c_str());
    libs.open(location.c_str());
if (libs.is_open()) {
    string lib;

       while(!libs.eof()) {
       getline(libs,lib);
        textfromcode+=lib;
        textfromcode+= '\n';
        }
        libs.close();
       }
return 0;
}
```

Im writing another file from `textfromcode` variable.

Comment: How are you writing the file? 65279 is 0xFEFF the UTF-16 BOM.  You are therefore trying to read a UTF-16 file one byte at a time.

Comment: I use this code for writing:
      ofstream myfile;
           myfile.open (argv[2]);
           if (myfile.is_open()){
           for (i=0;i < n;i++){
           myfile << code[i]<<'\n';
            }
           }
          myfile.close();
        }

Comment: So you have no idea what charset you´re using and why? (The UTF-8 "BOM" has the same decoded value)

Comment: So what i can use to fix that?

Comment: You can read many things about charsets. Seriously,. It´s probably UTF-8, so the difference to 1-byte-charsets can go unnoticed with the data, but as soon as try simple things like accessing single chars out of the string, you´ll have a problem. And there is no short-and-easy solution.

Comment: It would seem a properly setup `std::codecvt` with proper bom consumption via [`std::consume_header`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode) from `std::codecvt_mode` may be worth investigating, though it isn't exactly clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I try to read text from some files and to write it in one file but on every start of read file in that new file it write 65279 character.